# Função não reconhece elementos ocultos

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho uma função, ela funciona perfeitamente, porém preciso esconder os campos, que não necessitam aparecer para o cliente, porém quando oculto, a função não recebe os valores, estou utilizando desta forma:

```html
<div class="col-md-4" id="fim">
  <label id="lblFim" class="control-label">Data Fim</label>
  <input id="txtVencimentoC" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000" style="display:none" data-mask-reverser="false" />
  <input id="txtTol" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000" style="display:none" data-mask-reverser="false" />
  <input id="txtDataTolerancia" type="text" class="form-control" style="display:none" data-mask="00/00/0000" data-mask-reverser="false" />
  <input asp-for="PS.DataFim" id="txtDataFim" type="text" class="form-control" data-mask="00/00/0000" data-mask-reverser="false" />
</div>
```

Estou utilizando o:

```
style="display:none"
```

Lembrando que ele está dentro da div id=fim, e as vezes preciso esconder a div inteira.
Faço desta forma:

```
$("#fim").hide();
```

Como posso ocultar os campos, e eles continuarem funcionando na função ?

edit:
Como eu pego os dados na função:

```js
  function GravarDados() {
var dataInicio = $("#txtDataInicio").val();
var dataFim = $("#txtDataFim").val();
var diaVencimento = $("#txtDiaVencimento").val();
var tolerancia = $("#txtTolerancia").val();
var valor = $("#txtValor").val();
var planoId = $("#cbplanos option:selected").val();
var tipoPlano = $("#txtTipoPlano").val();
var pessoaId = $("#id").val();
var proporcional = $("#lblProporcional").val();
var dataTolerancia = $("#txtDataTolerancia").val();
var vencimentoC = $("#txtVencimentoC").val();
var descricao = $("#cbplanos option:selected").text();
var pre = $('#cbpre').prop('checked');
var pos = $('#cbpos').prop('checked');
var pro = $('#cbproporcional').prop('checked');
var url = "/PessoasServicos/Gravar";

$.ajax({
    url: url
    , data: { DataInicio: dataInicio, DataFim: dataFim, DiaVencimento: diaVencimento, Tolerancia: tolerancia, Valor: valor, PlanoId: planoId, TipoPlano: tipoPlano, PessoaId: pessoaId, Descricao: descricao, Proporcional: proporcional, Pre: pre, Pos: pos, Pro: pro, DataTolerancia: dataTolerancia, VencimentoC: vencimentoC}
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "html"
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado > 0) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
}
```

Se eu deixo ele visível, ele recebe os valores, se eu coloco o style="display:none" ele não recebe os valores.

Comment: Qual plugin você está usando ali, moça? Não seria o caso dessa lib estar ignorando elementos com `display: none`? Pode acrescentar essa informação à pergunta?

Comment: O teu código funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/gdt5zmo0/ podes mostrar a maneira exata de como o estás a usar?

Comment: Quando eu vou pegar os dados em uma função para passar para o controller, ele não recebe ela.

Comment: @Sergio será que, pelo fato de ela estar usando o ASP NET CORE, não poderia afetar? pois o seu teste não está levando em consideração a compilação que o Net Core faz

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com os dados, eu utilizo a mesma função em webforms, e funciona com o style="display:none", porém no ASPNET CORE, não funciona.

Comment: esse código é corrido " a seco" na página ou dentro de uma função? qual é o encadeamento de código para chegar a esse ponto? (cc @WallaceMaxters)

Comment: A função é chamada ao clicar no button, ela funciona, quando os elementos estão visíveis, se eu coloco o display none, ele não reconhece.

Comment: @Sergio minha preocupação é se o .NET CORE pode estar "removendo" elementos com  `display: none`. É só um palpite. Se ele altera comportamento da tag baseado num atributo, pensei que poderia ocorrer o mesmo no caso do display: none

Comment: Deu certo aqui, em vez de colocar display:none, na função mesmo eu escondendo, fazendo desta forma:  $("#txtDataTolerancia").hide();
                $("#txtVencimentoC").hide();

Answer (score 1):

Crie um Objeto no javascript e passe ele como parâmetros, no lugar de passar `data: { DataInicio: dataInicio,` , certamente sua controller não tem parâmetros opcionais e quando você não passa eles os dados não chagam na controller.

Tente fazer da seguinte forma.

```
var dados = Object();


dados.dataInicio = $("#txtDataInicio").val();
dados.dataFim = $("#txtDataFim").val();
dados.diaVencimento = $("#txtDiaVencimento").val();
dados.tolerancia = $("#txtTolerancia").val();
dados.valor = $("#txtValor").val();
dados.planoId = $("#cbplanos option:selected").val();
dados.tipoPlano = $("#txtTipoPlano").val();
dados.pessoaId = $("#id").val();
dados.proporcional = $("#lblProporcional").val();
dados.dataTolerancia = $("#txtDataTolerancia").val();
dados.vencimentoC = $("#txtVencimentoC").val();
dados.descricao = $("#cbplanos option:selected").text();
dados.pre = $('#cbpre').prop('checked');
dados.pos = $('#cbpos').prop('checked');
dados.pro = $('#cbproporcional').prop('checked');


$.ajax({
    url: url
    , data: { 'data':  dados}
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "html"
    , success: function (data) {
        if (data.resultado > 0) {
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult XXXXXXXXX(string data)
```

Comment: O problema não é este, quando os elementos estão visíveis ele recebe perfeitamente, já consegui resolver. Obrigado.